# is there any way or package which can run background tasks every minute periodically in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, background-process, android-workmanager, periodic-task

I am trying to build a flutter app for my company (just for android), in which we assign tasks to employees and track their location.

What I want to do, is to send http request every minute periodically to track their location, but I could not find any package or way to do that in the way I want.

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I have tried a lot of packages for background tasks. Including alarm_manager_plus, background_location, and work_manager package. the best one was workmanager package, but the frequency of repeating the background task was 15 minutes. I need to be able to run the background tasks at least every 5 minutes periodically.

Comment: i use one pacakge they help use to get location in background

Comment: Welcome! ⚠️️ Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package is help us to get location after app is kill
https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator

With this package you have to pass your detail via method channel into a native side for modification purpose